# Filter Productcollection by min_sale_qty

Tags: magento-1.9

i'm working on a productlisting with filterable on Minimum Selling Quantaty (min_sale_qty).

As i can see, the problem is, that this field isn't an normal Product Attribute, but an Stockitem Attribute.

Thus the normal way with `$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('min_sale_qty', ...)` or similar does not work. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Example code is:

```
    $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

    $filter_qty = 3;

    /* filter code */
    $_productCollection->joinTable(
          'cataloginventory/stock_item',
          'product_id=entity_id',
          array('min_sale_qty'),
          '{{table}}.min_sale_qty = ' . (int)$filter_qty,
          'inner'
    );
    //* filter code */

    echo $_productCollection->count();
```